# Deploy Shiny app that can read files from local computer (no possible Data-based solution)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to deploy a Shiny app on shinyapps, but it is not possible to read and write local files from the computer of the user. The idea is that every user can upload some datasets and images given a local path where this input is stored, not to have a same series of inputs for everyone stored in a ´Data´ folder.

I know there are other options to deploy shiny apps (amazon, shiny server), but I am afraid I will find the same kind of problems. Before losing too much time trying other approaches, I would like to know if there is any way to deploy a shiny app that can read these inputs given a local path and, if not, if there is an easy way to prepare an online app that can do this trasnlating from a shiny-based one. If not, I guess I will have to leave my app as a normal R package.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the expected user files are internally text files, you could deploy copy/past text area to alow users input their local file content. Just work with clipboard and handle all the security issues coming with.

Comment: Good answer. Unfortunately, there are quite a lot of files to read depending on many circumstances (it is necessary that the program outputs a lot of csv files with different kinds of data that can be easily accessed through other platforms). It is not a practical solution.

Comment: You still have option to host community shiny server by yourself, but then you have to make everything on your own.